# Shopify CLI - Shopify node serve is not working for 1 year old project

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, shopify, shopify-app

I am trying to refactor my old shopify project but, when I run command, "shopify node serve" It gives me the following error.

"This command can only be run within node projects."

But, It is a node project. It is a next.js shopify application.

Below is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "Announcement_Bar",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "forever start --minUptime 1000 server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production forever start --minUptime 1000 server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "@koa/cors": "^3.1.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@maxmind/geoip2-node": "^1.6.0",
    "@shopify/app-bridge": "^1.28.0",
    "@shopify/app-bridge-react": "^1.28.0",
    "@shopify/app-bridge-utils": "^1.28.0",
    "@shopify/koa-shopify-auth": "^3.2.0",
    "@shopify/koa-shopify-graphql-proxy": "^3.3.1",
    "@shopify/koa-shopify-webhooks": "^2.6.0",
    "@shopify/polaris": "^4.27.0",
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "ag-grid-community": "^22.1.1",
    "ag-grid-react": "^22.1.1",
    "agile_crm": "^1.2.5",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.2",
    "animate.css-react": "1.0.0",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.9",
    "bitly": "^7.1.2",
    "currency-formatter": "^1.5.6",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
    "draftjs-to-html": "^0.9.1",
    "emoji-picker-react": "^3.4.2",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
    "fbjs": "^3.0.0",
    "graphql": "^14.7.0",
    "he": "^1.2.0",
    "html-to-draftjs": "^1.5.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "javascript-obfuscator": "^0.24.6",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "koa": "^2.13.1",
    "koa-body": "^4.2.0",
    "koa-bodyparser": "^4.3.0",
    "koa-cache-control": "^2.0.0",
    "koa-conditional-get": "^2.0.0",
    "koa-etag": "^3.0.0",
    "koa-mongo": "^1.9.3",
    "koa-router": "^7.4.0",
    "koa-session": "^5.13.1",
    "koa-shopify-auth-cookieless": "^1.0.31",
    "koa-shopify-graphql-proxy-cookieless": "^1.0.11",
    "koa-static": "^5.0.0",
    "koa-static-cache": "^5.1.4",
    "koa2-formidable": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "mailchimp-api-v3": "^1.14.0",
    "mmmagic": "^0.5.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.4",
    "ms": "^2.1.3",
    "next": "^9.5.5",
    "node-cron": "^2.0.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.17",
    "notistack": "^0.9.17",
    "npm": "^7.5.2",
    "parse-link-header": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-apollo": "^3.1.5",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.3",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.16.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.14.5",
    "react-hotjar": "^2.2.1",
    "react-loading-overlay": "^1.0.1",
    "react-measure": "^2.5.2",
    "react-player": "^1.15.3",
    "react-select": "^3.2.0",
    "react-select-country-list": "^2.2.3",
    "react-slick": "^0.27.14",
    "react-world-flags": "^1.4.0",
    "shopify-jwt-auth-verify": "^1.0.10",
    "store-js": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

My node version is: 14.6.0
Shopify version: 2.6.5

I am not sure what is the problem, Only shopify node commands related to starting the server, are not working. All other shopify commands are working.

Comment: The first two things I'd try is a) updating b) reinstalling (deleting package-lock) und re-running `npm install`)

Comment: Alright, Gonna try that and will let u know

Answer (score 0):

For Shopify CLI 2.x the command is `shopify app serve`:
https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/tools/cli/cli-2#serve

If that doesn't work you should try migrating your app to Shopify CLI 3
https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/tools/cli/migrate